# Playonlinux questions

Tags: wine, playonlinux

1-playonlinux by default runs as root? If yes how to change it?
2 - Can playonlinux library script be malicious?
3-If I close playonlinux do the applications stop working? say I run a malware by playonlinux, after closing playonlinux does malware continue to work?

What is the best way to use playonlinux safely?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First an explanation of what PlayOnLinux is:

> PlayOnLinux is a GUI script engine that automates the Creation of wine prefixes, software installation, and creation of Launchers. It does not directly run any program. WINE runs the programs independent of PlayOnLinux. Once a prefix is created, PlayOnLinux could be removed with no effect on the installation of the Wine prefix.

1. PlayOnLinux does not run as root.
2. A script could be malicious. But unlikely if it is downloaded from PlayOnLinux's library.
3. PlayOnLinux does not run the program; Wine does. So closing PlayOnLinux has no effect on the program. PlayOnLinux doesn't even need to be running to Launch the Installed program.